# I have to sort an array using insertion sort and using recursion (without loops)

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I have to sort an array using insertion sort and using recursion without using loops. I have tried but it is not sorting anything. Here is my code:

```
def recursiveInsertionSort(array, i, j):
    n = len(array)
    if i < n:
        temp = array[i]
        j = i - 1
        if j >= 0 and array[j] > temp:
            array[j + 1] = array[j]
            recursiveInsertionSort(array, i, j - 1)
        array[j + 1] = temp
        recursiveInsertionSort(array, i + 1, j)
    return array

arr = [10, 8, 7, 50, 60, 3, 9, -1]
print(recursiveInsertionSort(arr, 1, 0))
```

Output is **[10, 8, 7, 50, 60, 3, 9, -1]** same as the given array. Expected output is **[-1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 60]** Can anyone help me to find where the problem is?

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Your code is suspicious - you pass a parameter j, but it is never used (you immediately overwrite its value with `j = i - 1`)

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind your code? Currently, you are showing us a code that doesn't work, and you expect us to understand what it was supposed to do and how to fix it so it does it correctly. Since it doesn't actually do what you want, we can't guess what you wanted to do. Please add english sentences to explain what i and j are, and what is the logic, and how this was supposed to be an implementation of insertion sort (for instance, where is the actual insertion happening?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly there are too many mistakes in your code for me to list off, but this works:

```
def recursiveInsertionSort(array, i, j):
    n = len(array)
    if i < n and j >= 0:
        if array[j] > array[j + 1]:
            temp = array[j + 1]
            array[j + 1] = array[j]
            array[j] = temp
        recursiveInsertionSort(array, i, j - 1)
    if j == 0:
        recursiveInsertionSort(array, i + 1, i)
    return array

arr = [10, 8, 7, 50, 60, 3, 9, -1]
print(recursiveInsertionSort(arr, 1, 0))
```

Output:

```
[-1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 60]
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignments, and other side effects.

We can write `insertion_sort(t)` using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). Starting with the input source `src = t` and an empty destination array `dst = []` -

1. If `src` is empty, there is nothing left to sort. Return the `dst` array
2. (inductive) `src` has at least one element. `insert` the first element `src[0]` into `dst` and recur on the sub-problem `src[1:]`

```py
def insertion_sort(t):
  def run(src, dst):
    if not src:
      return dst                                # 1
    else:
      return run(src[1:], insert(dst, src[0]))  # 2
  return run(t, [])
```

`insert(t, x)` can be written using the same technique -

1. If the input `t` is empty, the only possible output is `[x]`
2. (inductive) `t` has at least one element. If the first element `t[0]` is less than the element to insert `x`, then prepend `t[0]` to the result of the recursive sub-problem `insert(t[1:], x)`
3. (inductive) `t` the first element is greater than or equal to `x`. Prepend `x` to `t`

```py
def insert(t, x):
  if not t:
    return [x]                        # 1
  elif t[0] < x:
    return [t[0]] + insert(t[1:], x)  # 2
  else:
    return [x] + t                    # 3
```

Finally print the result

```py
arr = [10, 8, 7, 50, 60, 3, 9, -1]
print(insertion_sort(arr))
```

```py
[-1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 60]
```

**visualize**

Writing out the evaluation steps can help aid our ability to visualize how recursive computations grow.  First we look at the simpler of the two, `insert(t,x)`

```py
insert([3, 7, 8, 10, 50, 60], 9)
== [3] + insert([7, 8, 10, 50, 60], 9)
== [3] + [7] + insert([8, 10, 50, 60], 9)
== [3] + [7] + [8] + insert([10, 50, 60], 9)
== [3] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10, 50, 60]
== [3, 7] + [8] + [9] + [10, 50, 60]
== [3, 7, 8] + [9] + [10, 50, 60]
== [3, 7, 8, 9] + [10, 50, 60]
== [3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 60]
```

And now let's visualize `insertion_sort(t)` -

```py
insertion_sort([10, 8, 7, 50, 60, 3, 9, -1])
== run([10, 8, 7, 50, 60, 3, 9, -1], [])
== run([8, 7, 50, 60, 3, 9, -1], [10])
== run([7, 50, 60, 3, 9, -1], [8, 10])
== run([50, 60, 3, 9, -1], [7, 8, 10])
== run([60, 3, 9, -1], [7, 8, 10, 50])
== run([3, 9, -1], [7, 8, 10, 50, 60])
== run([9, -1], [3, 7, 8, 10, 50, 60])
== run([-1], [3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 60])
== run([], [-1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 60])
== [-1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 60]
```